# How to contact an external server from OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I have deployed an application on OpenShift that requires a connection to an external server 130.192.156.107:5000 but it seems not work. How can I open a connection from OpenShift? Is it possible? 
Thanks for the reply, Sonia.

Answer (score 1):

SSH into your gear and see if you can telnet to that ip address and port.  If you can't, try that from your local machine to, if it works on your local machine, post a bug to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online to see if the port is blocked.